# Combining unique observations in column

Tags: r

I am very new to R.I am trying to do a market basket analysis with a data frame with around 90000 transactions where order id has multiple items represented as multiple observations. This is in a large excel file. I am just giving the first 12 rows as a sample data frame.

```
order <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
time <- c(13.40,13.40,13.40,13.40,13.40,18.20,18.20,18.20,18.20,22.45,22.45,22.45,22.45,22.45,22.45,22.45)
item <-c('dal', 'napkin','rice','tooth paste','washing powder','tooth paste', 'dal', 'rice','chocolate', 'rice','dal','chocolate',tooth paste','veggies','napkin','toor dal')
dataframe <- data.frame(order, time,item)
```

Now I want to combine the orders and and make a sparse matrix of items. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Not clear about the expected output.  Perhaps `library(data.table); dcast(setDT(dataframe), order ~ item, length)`

Comment: _How_ do you want the orders to be combined? Counting number of items in each order?

Answer (score 0):

```
order <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
time <- c(13.40,13.40,13.40,13.40,13.40,18.20,18.20,18.20,18.20,22.45,22.45,22.45,22.45,22.45,22.45,22.45)
item <-c('dal', 'napkin','rice','tooth paste','washing powder','tooth paste', 'dal', 'rice','chocolate', 'rice','dal','chocolate','tooth paste','veggies','napkin','toor dal')
dataframe <- data.frame(order, time,item)

#seperate the Orders to one file each order
for( i in 1:length(unique(dataframe$order))){
  bez=paste("Order_",i,sep="")
  aux = subset(x = dataframe, subset = order ==i, select = c(order, item))
  assign(bez,aux)
}
#create a matrix with orders as columns and items as rows
matr = matrix(nrow = length(item), ncol = length(unique(order)))
rownames(matr) = item
aux = NA
#get 1 where an item is "ordered"
for(i in 1:length(unique(order))){
  aux = paste(get(paste("Order_",i,sep = ""))$item)
  matr[aux,i]=1
}
matr
```

You can run the code like this... Hope it is what you want.
If you have a question feel free to ask.

Cheers